# Wrong contentSize for UITableView after display modal

Tags: ios, uitableview, contentsize, presentviewcontroller

One of my tableview turn me crazy.

I have a scrollview with 3 tableviews inside.
But for a weird reason, my controller is unable to calculate the `contentSize.height` of one of those tableViews.

I've put 3 breakpoints to log it's `contentSize.height`.

- In `viewDidLoad`, `contentSize.height` = 0px (normal isn't it?)
- In `viewDidAppear:`, contentSize height = 26px . At this moment, I have no data to display, I'm retrieving some in background, and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return 0 for this tableview (and there is only 1 section for each tableView)
- After receiving my data and performed an `reloadData` on my tableView, contentSize height = 986 (header 26px + 24 rows * 40px)

Until here, everything looks normal.

Now, from my view controller, I'm displaying another view controller with : `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

When I come back to my initial view controller, I have kept my previous data. `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns me the 24 rows, but the `contentSize.height` of the tableview is 26px. My table just bounce when I try to scroll it, but my data is displayed in the table.

This problem **only appear with iOS 6**, not with iOS 7.

Any idea to fix this?

**Edit**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    timerRefresh = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(refreshMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    if(!isLoaded)
    {
        isLoaded = TRUE;
        //some stuff that have to be done once
        [self asynchGetDataWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary *result) {
            //process incoming data
            [myTable reloadData];
        }];
    }
}
```

*I invalidate my timer in `-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`*

Comment: what into your viewWillAppear? Share please

Comment: try [tableView setneedsLayout] or [tableView setneedsDisplay]

Comment: @santhu where to put this? `viewDidLoad` ? `viewDidAppear:`? anywhere else?

Comment: whenever you come back to your initial view controller after dismissing the modal,viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear will be fired, so call in either o them.put breakpoints in them to check whether they are called or not.

Comment: @santhu Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have to wait the next refresh, which include a `reloadData` to be able to scroll my `tableView`. I've tried to add `reloadTable` in `viewDidAppear`, but also doesn't have effect.

Comment: @zbMax:put bareak point in scrollDidscroll and see when you return back to initial controller there is any action in that method

Comment: @Seeker the breakpoint in `scrollViewDidScroll:` is reached when I scroll my tableView, and after `presentViewController: animated: completion:`.

Comment: @zbMax: are you present a viewcontroller or navigationController. If you present viewcontroller the tableview contentset will change

Comment: @Seeker Yes, I'm presenting a subclass of `UIViewController`. Admitting that this is the source of my problem, why are my 2 others tableViews' contentSize unchanged? This weird behavior on the first tableView is independent of what event show me the modal view (button pressed, cell selected, etc...)

Comment: I've also noticed that I reach the breakpoint in `scrollViewDidScroll:` when presenting a view controller only once.

Comment: nslog the tableView.contentOffset.y in scrollDidScroll and scroll your tableview. see your nslog values it start from 0 or -20

Comment: It always starts from 0